# Load store once

Tags: extjs

I have one store, and many places where this Store loaded(two grids,combobox and etc.) How make so that store load once, and grids take data without load store.  for example when displaying grid with data from Store, store didn't load , grid only show data which already loaded on store

Comment: Are you using MVC architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you manually telling the store to load from those other places?  You could instead try and use the `autoLoad` config of the store.  Another option would be to check the `isLoaded()` method (ext js 5) on the Store before triggering a load.